# How to add the id from the certain div element in a javascript array?

Tags: javascript

```
    <td class="row" id="253">
    <select class="available-room" style="" id="roomToBook">
<option value="0">Select</option>
<option value=1>1</option>
<option value=2>2</option>
<option value=3>3</option>
<option value=4>4</option>
<option value=5>5</option>
<option value=6>6</option>
<option value=7>7</option>
<option value=8>8</option>
<option value=9>9</option>
<option value=10>10</option>
</select>`enter code here`
    </td>
     <td class="row" id="253">
    <select class="available-room" style="" id="roomToBook">
<option value="0">Select</option>
<option value=1>1</option>
<option value=2>2</option>
<option value=3>3</option>
<option value=4>4</option>
<option value=5>5</option>
<option value=6>6</option>
<option value=7>7</option>
<option value=8>8</option>
<option value=9>9</option>
<option value=10>10</option>
</select>              </td>
     <td class="row" id="253">
    <select class="available-room" style="" id="roomToBook">
<option value="0">Select</option>
<option value=1>1</option>
<option value=2>2</option>
<option value=3>3</option>
<option value=4>4</option>
<option value=5>5</option>
<option value=6>6</option>
<option value=7>7</option>
<option value=8>8</option>
<option value=9>9</option>
<option value=10>10</option>
</select>              </td>
```

I have a three table cell having different id. Here i want to get the id when user select the option of respective id and add  id in a array when user select the two or more then two option value from different table cell in a same time.
I have a javascript  code also.It shows same id in alert frequently in every selection of option value of same id.Please someone help me.

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
 $(document).on('change', '.available-room', function () {
     var room_id =  new Array();
      room_id.push($(this).parent('td').attr('id'));
      alert(room_id);
    });
     });
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `id` attributes **must** be unique in the document, you can't use the same `id` on more than one element. So that's the first thing to fix. If you need to group elements together, `class` is useful. (You'll also get people telling you `id`s can't be numeric. They can, but if you need to use CSS selectors with numeric `id` values, it's a pain. \[The [only restrictions](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) are they must be unique, can't contain spaces, and must have at least one character if given.])

Comment: You are right sir, i forgot to change the id value during asking the question. This id attribute is all time unique in my project , which comes from the database.Thanks for your complement.

Answer (score 1):

You must declare id as unique in a file so you can get value by `$(this).val()` and array declaration `var room_id = new Array()` must be outside `.on('change',function(){....});`

```
        <table>
            <td class="row" id="roomToBook_1">
                <select class="available-room" style="" id="roomToBook1">
                    <option value="0">Select</option>
                    <option value=1>1</option>
                    <option value=2>2</option>
                    <option value=3>3</option>
                    <option value=4>4</option>
                    <option value=5>5</option>
                    <option value=6>6</option>
                    <option value=7>7</option>
                    <option value=8>8</option>
                    <option value=9>9</option>
                    <option value=10>10</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class="row" id="roomToBook_2">
                <select class="available-room" style="" id="roomToBook2">
                    <option value="0">Select</option>
                    <option value=1>1</option>
                    <option value=2>2</option>
                    <option value=3>3</option>
                    <option value=4>4</option>
                    <option value=5>5</option>
                    <option value=6>6</option>
                    <option value=7>7</option>
                    <option value=8>8</option>
                    <option value=9>9</option>
                    <option value=10>10</option>
                </select>              </td>
            <td class="row" id="roomToBook_3">
                <select class="available-room" style="" id="roomToBook3">
                    <option value="0">Select</option>
                    <option value=1>1</option>
                    <option value=2>2</option>
                    <option value=3>3</option>
                    <option value=4>4</option>
                    <option value=5>5</option>
                    <option value=6>6</option>
                    <option value=7>7</option>
                    <option value=8>8</option>
                    <option value=9>9</option>
                    <option value=10>10</option>
                </select>              </td>
        </table>


        <script>

            $(document).ready(function () {
                var room_id = new Array();
                $(document).on('change', '.available-room', function () {

                    room_id.push($(this).val());
                    //alert(room_id);
                    alert(JSON.stringify(room_id));
                });
            });


        </script>
```

Comment: Not working sir. I want the id attributes not the selected option value. And another thing is that the id should be added in the array not in every selection but in one selection of option value.

Comment: Then you use `$(this).attr("id");` to get id

Comment: I have done this already. The main  problem is that alert frequently throw the same id when selecting the different option value. Do you have any idea about  to get only  one id ? Please help.